# AmazonAWS securing S3 Bucket videos

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, video, amazon-s3

I'm using the AWS S3 bucket in a very simple way.

- There's a bucket, <somebucket1>
- There's a folder, <somebucket1>/sitevideos
- And video files in it, <somebucket1>/sitevideos/video.mp4

I use this bucket so playback using HTML5 video (`<video></video>`) is more optimised and doesn't lag compared to just calling the video from the same server of the website (which is ridiculous).

The video files are encrypted, but they are set to be read-only to Public.

Now, my worries are, because they are *public*, people can download them from the S3 bucket instead of playing them on the website.

## The Question

Is there a way to play a video file in S3 bucket, on an HTML video from a remote website, but will refuse downloads of the file if they are accessed directly via the S3 path?

If there are tutorials for this, I'd appreciate it.  If this is already on the S3 documentation, I apologise for the laziness, please show me the link.  I also heard that you can set them the permission to private, but they can still play on a remote server (although I haven't made that work).

Cheers & many thanks

Comment: why are they set to public and not private?

Comment: May be helpful to read Restricting Access to a Specific HTTP Referrer at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4.

Comment: @smith, when I tried to set the folder to private, the videos won't play on the website using HTML5 video.  If I have some configuration misunderstanding, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Bucket Policy can be configured to [Restrict Access to a Specific HTTP Referrer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4).

For example, if a web page includes an image on the page, then the HTTP request for that object will include a `referer`. (I presume this would work for a video, too.)

However, this is not very good security, since the HTTP request can be easily manipulated to include the `referer` (eg in a web scraper).

A more secure method would be to use a [Pre-Signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html). This is a specially-constructed URL that grants time-limited access to a private Amazon S3 object.

When rendering the web page, your app would determine whether the user is permitted to access the object. If so, it would construct the pre-signed URL using AWS credentials. The URL can then be included in the standard HTML tags (eg `<img src='...'>`). The user will be able to access the object until the expiry time. If they shared the URL with somebody else (eg in a Tweet), other people would also be able to access the object until the expiry time.

By the way, [Amazon CloudFront can also serve video content](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/streaming/) using various video protocols. It also supports pre-signed URLs (and also signed cookies).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed, good answer.  I have a little follow up: if the URL can expire, would that mean I would have to update the URL assigned on the webpage everytime it expires? Albeit insecure than the latter, I think my best shot would be to use restricted Access to a Specific HTTP Referrer method - unless there's a way to get around not having to update video URLs when they expire.

Comment: Don't think of it as "updating" the URL. Rather, the page should generate the pre-signed URL on-the-fly when the page is being produced (just like personalizing a page by putting somebody's name on it). So, every time the app generates the page, it produces a new signed URL that is valid for the next _N_ minutes. It's just a couple of lines of code. Much more secure than using `referer`.